# clicking on the bottom of the list gets the element from top of the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Java` and `Selenium` to write a test. Somewhere in the targeted application, i have a list, so I need to click on an element at the bottom of a list. I use the code below:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='4']"))).click();
```

the DOM for that list looks like:

```
<div class="verde-items services-items">
    <div class="verde-item service" data-service="271">
        <div role="button" data-selector-btn="">
            <span class="verde-item-name service-name">1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="verde-item service" data-service="329">
        <div role="button" data-selector-btn="">
            <span class="verde-item-name service-name">2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="verde-item service" data-service="269">
        <div role="button" data-selector-btn="">
            <span class="verde-item-name service-name">3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="verde-item service" data-service="270">
        <div role="button" data-selector-btn="">
            <span class="verde-item-name service-name">4</span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

the problem is that when I use chrome it works but when I use firefox it scrolls down to the bottom of the list where the element is BUT it tries to click on top of the list so I get the error:

> Element is not clickable at point (781, 9). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: Can you add the full error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

As you're saying this element is at bottom which to be visible after scrolling.

`Selenium` tries to scroll to the element and then click on it. This is because `Selenium` will not interact with an element unless it thinks that it is visible.

Scrolling to the element happens implicitly so you just need to find the item and then work with it as below :-

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='4']")));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, actually my question was why it's not happening at Chrome?

Comment: Its may be browser behaviour that's why there you're facing the problem, but you could resolve it by provided generic solution.. thanks..:)

Comment: actually I rsolved it by using action to clcik on the lemnet, the main issue is that my test should be useable for FireFox, Chrome and Safary, would you know how can I write a code that works for all ?

Comment: In this case Using actions is the good option, I think I would be work for all browser, and as second solution you can use JavascriptExecutor to perform click which will work for all browser also..:)

Comment: @LoveLovelyJavaone For Best way, you should try to make element into view before click which would be work in all browser. To achieving this you can use Actions as well as JavascriptExecutor.. thanks..:)